# How to connect to a BLE device the second time in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on an app where I connect to a BLE device. I can successfully connect, pass data back and forth, etc. The problem I am having is when I run the app the second time. If I try to connect to the device a second time, after pairing to it the first time, nothing seems to happen. I press my 'connect' button and I get nothing. To get it to connect again, I have to go into Settings, select the device, and forget the device. Once I have done this, everything works fine.

I am sure there is a simple way to connect to "reconnect" to the device, but I can't seem to find any information on how to do this. If fact, it looks like I am still connected to the device at the system level, but I need to know what to do to load it back into my local CBPeripheral variable.

Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

This is my current connection code:

```
private var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
private var peripheral: CBPeripheral!


centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil) //init central manager

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        Print("Central state update")
        switch central.state {
        case .poweredOn:
            Print("Bluetooth is On, Starting scan.")
            peripheral_list.removeAll()
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil,
                                              options: nil)
            case .unknown:
                Print("central.state is 'unknown'")
            case .resetting:
                Print("central.state is 'resetting'")
            case .unsupported:
                Print("central.state is 'unsupported'")
            case .unauthorized:
                Print("central.state is 'unauthorized'")
            case .poweredOff:
                Print("central.state is 'poweredOff'")
            @unknown default:
                Print("central.state **** Default *****")
        }
    }
    
    public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        
        if let name = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataLocalName"] {
            if true /*name as! String == "RyanBT"*/ {
                Print("\nName   : \(name)")
                Print("UUID   : \(peripheral.identifier)")
                Print("RSSI   : \(RSSI)")
                for ad in advertisementData {
                    Print("AD Data: \(ad)")
                }
                
                peripheral_list.append(peripheral)
                picker.reloadAllComponents()
            }
        }
    }

    
    // The handler if we do connect succesfully
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        if peripheral == self.peripheral {
            Print("Connected!!!")
            peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        }
    }
    
    func connectToDevice() {
        
        // Stop scan before connecting
        self.centralManager.stopScan()
        
        
        self.peripheral = self.peripheral_list[rowSelected]   //use selected peripheral
        self.peripheral.delegate = self
        
        // Connect!
        self.centralManager.connect(self.peripheral, options: nil)
    }
```

Edit:
I added this code:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            Print("\(error!)")
        }
    }
```

And this is the message it is printing when I try to connect the second time:

> Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=14 "Peer removed pairing
> information" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Peer removed pairing
> information}

Answer (score 2):

An iPhone can be connected to a BLE device even when your app is not connected. The actual device connection is handled by the OS, and shared among apps. While connected, most devices will not advertise, so you won't find them in `didDiscover`. This is all completely normal, particularly if you never disconnect by calling `cancelPeripheralConnection`. But even then it can happen.

Assuming that you're connecting to specific devices that advertise specific services, you should change your `scanForPeripherals` call to pass those services rather than nil. As a rule you shouldn't pass nil to `scanForPeripherals` unless you're building a general-purpose scanner. It's slower, and can return devices you don't want.

If you do that, you can then check for already connected devices by calling `retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices:)`. Given your current code, you would likely do that inside `centralManagerDidUpdateState`.

Alternately, you could keep track of individual devices that you've seen before by their peripheral UUIDs (by storing them in UserDefaults for example). You can check if those specific peripherals are currently connected using `retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:)`. Again, you'd probably do this in `centralManagerDidUpdateState`.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback! My scenario is a little different than this. The device I'm connecting to does not advertise services. Also, when I scan, I do see the device again, it just doesn't do anything when I try to connect to it the second time.

Comment: check `retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:)` in that case. I suspect it's already connected. This is a somewhat unusual device (most BLE devices advertise *some* service), so I would also check the device itself and make sure it's not getting into a bad state if you control its firmware.

Comment: Hey Rob, I wasn't having any luck with retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:) so I added the didFailToConnect callback (I edited my original post). Do you know what it could mean when it says this? Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=14 "Peer removed pairing information" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Peer removed pairing information}

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error. I would first suspect a disconnection from the peripheral side, but you can read some iOS 13-related discussion on the forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/132488

Comment: Thanks Rob! Unfortunately that thread doesn't look very promising. It looks like they are also going into settings to forget the device. I'll try to reach out to the people working on the device firmware to see if they have any solutions.