# iPhone 13 Swift Connecting to BLE Peripherals a Second Time

Tags: swift, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy

The notion that CBCentralManager::Connect won't trigger a centralManager didConnect once it's listed in iPhone Settings -> Bluetooth creates problems for caching the services and characteristics.

Trying to find a way of getting a connected peripheral:

1. CBCentralManager::scanForPeripherals will refind the peripheral, but it is not connected.  Calling connect the second time is not successful.
2. CBCentralManager::retrievePeripherals with the ID from the scan call results in the same unconnected peripheral.  It would be nice if this call supported nil like scanForPeripherals to find all peripherals, but I digress.
3. CBCentralManager::retrieveConnectedPeriphreals(withServices but the list is empty.  Same nil observation.

Yes, in each of these cases on the second attempt (second app instance), I waited for centralManagerUpdateState to process and be in the poweredOn state before attempting any of these find the peripheral methods.

It sounds like this is expected behavior for some.  But if it's expected behavior, how to people rediscover the services and characteristics?
[How to connect to a BLE device the second time in iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710187/how-to-connect-to-a-ble-device-the-second-time-in-ios-swift)

The whole point of wanting to discover peripherals and characteristics is that setNotifyValue, readValue or writeValue require the CBPeripheral and CBCharacteristic instances.  Which I can cache in memory if I can discover them.

My temporary work around is to go into Apple Settings Bluetooth and Forget the peripheral in question.  Once I do this, the connect call works just fine.  It sounds like Apple really doesn't want applications to be able to forget peripherals without the end users involvement, which makes sense from a security standpoint.  So this is obviously not good flow.

Hoping someone can provide a helpful way of looking at this from another perspective.